# No normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is normal in $G$ if and only if $gH = Hg$ for all $g$ in $G$ and a simple group is a nontrivial group whose only normal subgroups are the trivial group and the group itself, but I was wondering if there is a group with no normal subgroups?

Comment: There isn't. If $G$ is a group, then both $\{e\}$ and $G$ are normal subgroups in $G$.

Comment: no. every group has at least the trivial group as a subgroup.

Answer (score 2):

The identity subgroup $\{1\}\subset G$ and $G$ are  always a normal subgroups which are distinct if $G$ is not trivial.